# Why does iOS require launch image?

Tags: ios

Is the launch image a must for an iOS application? How long will it be shown when app launches, can we control the duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS documentation states that a launch image is a requirement for App Store submission, however I currently have an app available that does not have one (simply forgot to add it) so it would seem it is something they are not overly strict about enforcing or the documentation (that I read, at least) is incorrect

The image itself is shown while the application is initiated. You can control the duration by making it so that your app launches faster (or slower, though I do not know why you would want to do that).

It is required so that the OS has something to show while the app initializes (since the system cannot screenshot the app and use that as it does when switching between apps)

Comment: One benefit of this image is that, if used correctly, it will make your app seem like it is loading faster than it really is. Look at Apple Notes, for example. The UI seems to load in stages, which you perceive as faster than looking at a blank screen until it is fully loaded.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg That is a very good point and it looks like Apple actually does that with _all_ of their applications.

Comment: To be more specific, it will be shown until your app delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching method returns. If you want to "make your app launch faster", move any lengthy operations out of that method.

Answer (score 1):

From page 204 onwards, of Apple's [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf) document,

> To enhance the user’s experience at app launch, you must provide at
>   least one launch image. A launch image looks very similar to the first
>   screen your app displays. iOS displays this image instantly when the
>   user starts your app and until the app is fully ready to use.
>
> As soon as your app is ready for use, your app displays its first
>   screen, replacing the launch placeholder image.

You cannot control the duration, however, if you set a launch image (as you are required to do anyway) and create a special root view controller that displays this same image, then once the launch image is removed your controller is visible. This controller is commonly used in games, perhaps playing some music for a main menu and presenting some options. It will make the launch image transition appear flawless.

Answer (score 0):

The launch image is shown while your application is being loaded. The faster your application loads and gets its first view on screen the shorter the duration the launch image will be shown. So, you can't directly control the duration, but by ensuring you application loads quickly you can affect it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) says launch images are required, they are not from technical stand point. For example, all my development work runs fine without a launch image.

What it does do is, if your app takes a fair amount of time to launch (think of games, or HootSuite for a concrete example), it provides the user some feedback, essentially saying the device has not frozen while everything gets started.

Comment: Additionally, having a default@2x-568h.png launch image tells the phone your app wants to use iPhone 5 screen size, and not having it tells the iPhone 5 to use the older 320x480 screen size.

Answer (score -4):

I've never created an iOs application, but I have done Flash. Launch images are for when the program is loading. So the bigger your program the longer the image will be shown. IF you do not need a launch image, it still is recommended because a boring black screen will cause several problems:

- It will cause the user to think it didn't work. And become frusterated.
- It will be more appealing. Sometimes this could even make or break the success of your application. Appearances are everything in today's environment.